# Cant react with a custom Emoji in discord.py: (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently studying discord.py, but I was really stuck when I tried to make a custom emote reaction on my bot.

Here's the code:

```
import discord
from unidecode import unidecode

def get_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Working, logged on as', self.user)
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        message.content = str(message.content).lower()
        message.content = unidecode(str(message.content))
        if message.content == 'sabs':
            await message.add_reaction("")
        elif message.content == 'cafe':
            await message.add_reaction("")
        elif message.content == 'pato':
            await message.add_reaction("<:pato:762694521904431145>")

client = MyClient()
client.run(get_token())
```

I also tried to (":pato:762694521904431145"), or use just the ID...

Some information:
discord.py tested versions: (1.4.1/1.5.0)
python tested verson: (3.8/3.7)
PyCharm IDE

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct ID? Copying an emoji in a message gives you the message ID, not emoji. To find the ID do `\:EMOJI_NAME:` and then you'll get something that looks like `<:ABCDE:12345>` that should work with your emoji. Another possible cause is you using a string instead of the `discord.Emoji()` class in your reaction function. Try using `client.get_emoji(ID_GOES_HERE)`

Comment: Can you print out the `unidecode(str(message.content))`? What is the output?

Comment: @Nurqm Unicode function doesn't exist in python 3. `message.content` also comes as a string since discord disallows sending raw bytes in messages.

Comment: @EricJin omg, that was exactly the problem, I feel silly for a mistake like that, 
i spent all day yesterday doing everything wrong lol, thank you very much for your answer!